# Force spaces to convert to %20 from HTML input field using js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have an input field on my site which people can enter search terms.

I am taking the value of the users input and spitting it out onto a url string.

```js
jQuery("#searchButton").click(function(){
    var simpleSearchTermLocal = jQuery('#searchField').val();
    var urlString = "www.mysite.com/" + simpleSearchTermLocal;
    alert(urlString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchField" />
<button id="searchButton">search</button>
```

So when someone inputs something like "ABC" into the search field, the value of variable `urlString` becomes `www.mysite.com/ABC` which is fine.

But when entering a space in the input field, like "ABC 123", `urlString` becomes `www.mysite.com/ABC 123` which isnt fine. I would like it to turn into `www.mysite.com/ABC%20123`

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the **[`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)** function.

```js
var theString = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";

console.log(encodeURI(theString));
```

Comment: Awesome this is the answer, thanks!